# What's the difference between DisplayPort, DVI and HDMI?

Tags: video, hdmi, dvi, displayport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [HDMI vs Component vs VGA vs DVI vs DisplayPort](https://superuser.com/questions/15884/hdmi-versus-component-versus-vga-versus-dvi)
> [Is Displayport preferable to DVI for monitor connections?](https://superuser.com/questions/10758/is-displayport-preferable-to-dvi-for-monitor-connections)

**As an end consumer, are there any significant differences between the newer DisplayPort interface and DVI/HDMI that I should be aware of?**

I realize they are different connector types and require compatible equipment, I'm primarily interested in whether there are functional or performance benefits of one technology over another.

Should I have a preference for one technology or another on newer video card equipment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert almost anyway you want.

HDMI and DVI are electrically compatible. DVI-I is also electrically compatible with VGA if you need analog support.

HDMI is currently at v1.4 has several version idiosyncrasy that can be frustrating. Unless you are buying all new equipment, you will run across these.

DisplayPort, some feel, is a bit more susceptible to noise. While the DP spec allows for PCM audio, most current implementations do not support audio.

It depends on your use. DP is great for computer / monitor use. HDMI is better for home theater / pro video use.

I use DisplayPort for all the office stuff I do. My monitors are all configured with DP in and laptops / desktops are all DP out.

Home theater is more friendly to HDMI.

Just pick a standard that works for you, and you convert if you need to.