# My laptop has an HDMI output, and my monitor has DVI, VGA and DisplayPort - how do I not lose video performance?

Tags: hdmi, vga, dvi, displayport, display-adapter

So as the question states, my gaming laptop has an HDMI video out (also a USB-C out, but I assume it is not connected to the nVidia graphics card), and I need to connect it to my monitor, which has VGA, DVI-D and DisplayPort inputs.

So I'm in need of some kind of an adapter. Which should I buy? HDMI->DVI-D, HDMI->VGA or HDMI->DPort?

Is there a video performance benefit to any of them over the others? I plan to run high end games at 1080p and expect 60fps when possible.

Comment: HDMI and DVI are actually electrically compatible, see this question: [What's the difference between DisplayPort, DVI and HDMI?](https://superuser.com/questions/142457/whats-the-difference-between-displayport-dvi-and-hdmi), and/or it's duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DisplayPort would be the best option, since it will carry both video and audio while exceeding HDMI's specs. Adapters are a little pricey due to lack of demand/popularity.

DVI-D is an acceptable option, but won't transport audio. HDMI-to-DVI-D adapters are fairly widely available and not very expensive.

Don't use VGA or DVI-A. Conversion of the digital signal to analog will introduce delay, and the adapter won't be cheap.

Comment: My monitor doesn't do audio - will I lose quality by getting an HDMI to DVI-D instead of HDMI->DPort at my requirements?

Comment: Your resolution will be limited to 1920x1080x60, but otherwise no.